# How to redirect to HTTPS with .htaccess on Heroku Cedar stack

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, heroku, load-balancing

I'm new to cloud hosting...

I'm working on a PHP web app that's hosted on Heroku as a "Cedar" app. Heroku offers "piggy back" SSL to all their subdomains, so I can load `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` just fine. But I can also load `http://myapp.herokuapp.com`. I want to force SSL by redirecting `http` requests to `https`.

Normally, this would be easy. I would just use mod_rewrite as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**BUT THIS DOESNT WORK ON HEROKU!**

It appears that SSL terminates upstream, before the traffic ever hits my app. So the `%{HTTPS}` condition is never met, and the result is a redirect loop. I've also tried the following, which also didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} != 443 #<--also redirect loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https #<--also redirect loop
```

So my question is how can I detect/redirect-to HTTPS when it's terminated upstream?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

After spending all day on this, I figured it out!!

The issue is eloquently summarized in the book [Professional Heroku Programming](http://books.google.ca/books?id=GRI-9o6phYMC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=heroku%20https%20between%20load%20balancer%20and%20app&source=bl&ots=oX7Lfe66kA&sig=apwUytSBGuyNi4qjUGhakEbLdtY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4YdGVLeEOurlsATX7YGwCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=heroku%20https%20between%20load%20balancer%20and%20app&f=false).

Bottom line: Heroku sets its own custom header to indicate the ORIGINAL scheme of the traffic (before SSL terminated at the load balancer).

So THIS works in an .htaccess file on Heroku

```
##Force SSL 

#Normal way (in case you need to deploy to NON-heroku)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

#If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The secret sauce is the line with `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Hope this helps someone else having the same issues! At the time of writing this there is ZERO documentation on this.

Comment: I wish I would have found this yesterday :(

Comment: This just helped us out greatly. Thanks SDP

Comment: Been banging my head on a wall for the last three hours trying to figure this out. This solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Remember to add "RewriteEngine On" at the beginning

Comment: This also helped me out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#apache

Comment: Would you mind sharing the entire .htaccess file? I'm not sure where exactly in .htaccess to put this snippet.

Comment: Second time this has helped me! Wish I could upvote again.

Comment: how can i check the useragent on heroku

Comment: Where do you place this file and how do you check if Heroku is picking it up?

Answer (score 2):

I added one line to the great answer given above so it doesn't break my local dev environment which doesn't have SSL configured:

```
# If header is present in the request
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} .
```

(Note RewriteRule is applied only if [all preceeding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) RewriteCond's hold).

Answer (score 0):

If heroku is not picking up your .htaccess file you might have to use a a custom application level Apache configuration as documented by [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#using-a-custom-application-level-apache-configuration)

Basically you'll need to add this to your profile: 
`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C apache_app.conf`