# Apache mod_rewrite Infinite Loop when Accessing WordPress Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site that I am trying to set up with SSL.  The site is working except for the admin dashboard, which results in this error in Chrome:

*ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

I found a post on StackOverflow that helped with the HTTPS redirect, since Heroku apparently does things a bit differently.  Nonetheless, I'm still stuck with the error.

I've added this to my wp-config.php file, with no luck:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions


#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489519/how-to-redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-on-heroku-cedar-stack/26494983#26494983
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
##Force SSL 
#Normal way (in case you need to deploy to NON-heroku)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

#If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I run curl --verbose --head --location ,

I see that it is redirecting back and forth from http://easyofficepools.herokuapp.com and https://easyofficepools.herokuapp.com.  I'm not sure where the http redirect is coming from.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

EDIT:  I also noticed that the PINGBACK info from curl is http ,and not https:

```
< X-Pingback: http://easyofficepools.herokuapp.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Pingback: http://easyofficepools.herokuapp.com/xmlrpc.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a duplicate (alas, one that eluded me for 2 hours)!

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170165/wordpress-wp-admin-https-redirect-loop

I needed to add this to my wp-config.php:

```
/** SSL */  
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain  
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https  
// so check for https existence  
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)  
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```