# Heroku redirect Next.js React client app http to https

Tags: reactjs, ssl, heroku, https, next.js

I have an express server deployed on Heroku: https://server.mydomain.com

and a Next.js React app also deployed on Heroku: https://app.mydomain.com

Both have their SSL certificates automatically configured by Heroku, and when I visit the https domains, they work as expected.

**The problem I have** is that when I visit http://app.mydomain.com, it does not redirect to https://app.mydomain.com.

All the solutions I've found online point to forcing SSL on the server:

- [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect) says to check for the `x-forwarded-proto` value:

```
/* At the top, with other redirect methods before other routes */
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
 if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']!='https')
   res.redirect('https://app.mydomain.com'+req.url)
 else
   next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
})
```

- and others suggest using a package like [express-sslify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify) or [heroku-ssl-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect).

These solutions work fine **for the server requests**, but loading a React client page does not necessarily trigger `app.get()`. Obviously, a React client can run independently of a server.

**So the question is:** How does someone force https for a subdomain Next.js React client app on Heroku? Without using express server methods?

Comment: Are you paying for your dynos?

Comment: I have two apps deployed to Heroku, one on a paid account, and one on a non-paid account.  The paid one will automatically re-route to https out of the box, the free one does not.

Comment: Yes. Both are paid.

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: Where do you load the React app from? is it from http://app.mydomain.com?

Comment: Yes. The React (Next.js) app is hosted on it's own app on a hobby dyno with a custom domain.

Comment: Slept on it and `Obviously, a React client can run independently of a server.` sticks out.  A client needs a server and heroku is serving up your static folder most likely via a node server (I think that's the default web server).  What you'll need to do is build an express app that serves up your static build files instead and have a Procfile that tells heroku to run node against that express app instead of directly against your react app.

Comment: @JakeLuby this sounds like a good route, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that. I have the Next.js app, and deploy using Heroku's cli. How exactly do you build an express server that serves it up? Another app in Heroku?

Comment: If it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489519/how-to-redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-on-heroku-cedar-stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do this in one of my production applications.

We prepare the next app object and init an express server. This is done in the **server.js** file. You can read more about it in the [docs about a custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-server-and-routing).

Next.js also has an example in their github in the examples folder about a custom express server. It's [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/custom-server-express/server.js).

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {

    const server = express();

    server.use((req, res, next) => {
      const hostname = req.hostname === 'www.app.domain.com' ? 'app.domain.com' : req.hostname;

      if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http' || req.hostname === 'www.app.domain.com') {
        res.redirect(301, `https://${hostname}${req.url}`);
        return;
      }

      res.setHeader('strict-transport-security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload');
      next();
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

    server.listen(
      4242,
      error => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.error('Listening on port 4242');
      }
    );

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

As for deploying to Heroku you should be able to just customize the **npm start** script to start nextjs like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

Heroku also runs **npm run build** automatically so it should build the app for you.

Comment: And in the context of a Next.js app, where do you put this exactly, and how do you deploy it Heroku?

Comment: @5tormTrooper thought it was obvious... I'm gonna update the answer

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. It worked! Thank you for taking the time to outline it so clearly. Much appreciated! 

Comment: @5tormTrooper glad I could help :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a custom server?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku does not currently "offer out of the box" functionality to [force the use of `https` for node apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862065/force-my-heroku-app-to-use-ssl-https).

However, with the release of Nextjs v12 you can accomplish this without having to setup a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and use [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) instead.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458059/how-do-i-force-or-redirect-my-next-js-website-to-use-https/70311570#70311570) for example code and advantages of `middleware` vs `custom server`.

I also published a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-ssl-redirect-middleware) to handle this:

```js
import sslRedirect from 'next-ssl-redirect-middleware';
export default sslRedirect({});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @joão-cunha is great and worked for me as well. I had to make a few minor adjustments for this to work with my heroku app (deployed late 2023).

my heroku NODE_ENV is lowercase production.  The following change resolved

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION'
```

to

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

using or in the if statement resulted in an error due seemingly due to infinite redirects as the app redirected, hit the middleware - passed the if conditional, and redirected again.  Also the req.url was evaluating to https, so I removed it from the redirect

So the change for me was from

```
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http' || req.hostname === 'www.app.domain.com') {
    res.redirect(301, `https://${hostname}${req.url}`);
    return;
  }
```

to

```
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http' && req.hostname === 'www.app.domain.com') {
    res.redirect(301, `https://${hostname}`);
    return;
  }
```

Otherwise worked like a charm.  Big thanks to @5tormTrooper for the question and João Cunha for the answer.